# Run a ClickOnce application from a webpage without user action

Tags: c#, javascript, clickonce

We have a Java based web-application and also the same application written in C# which should be run if the java-checker finds out that there's no Java installed on the client machine. The idea is to run the C# [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application automatically, without any user action, once the Java checker reports that there's no Java installed on the machine. Is that possible and if yes - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just link to (or redirect the browser to) the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) of the ClickOnce application. That should launch the application.

For example, http://www.domain.com/myapp.application

Comment: unfortunately it is not that easy