# Launching a ClickOnce application from another ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, clickonce

My goal is to actually achieve launching my ClickOnce application in one click (or two I guess).  The application has some prerequisites which need to be installed. The normal way of ensuring they are installed that Microsoft provides involves having the user decide whether he has the prerequisites or not and downloading and installing a "setup.exe" which installs them and runs the ClickOnce application. This involves downloading the EXE file (one click), running it (two clicks), then after prerequisites are installed, clicking again to run the ClickOnce application.

I'm trying to reduce this process to one or two clicks:
- Click a link on my website to the ClickOnce `.application` file.
- Click again to run it.

I have made ANOTHER ClickOnce application, which includes a setup.exe. It checks if the prerequisites are installed, and if they are it runs the other ClickOnce application automatically. If not, it runs the included setup.exe and then runs the other ClickOnce application.

My problem is that when I try to run the other ClickOnce application from this one, it simply opens my web browser and downloads the .application file without running it.

I'm trying to use the following to start the ClickOnce application from inside my C# code:

```
Process.Start(ApplicationURL);
```

I just want this to automatically launch the application at ApplicationURL. Is there a way to skip the browser involvement that I'm seeing?

(My question is very similar to Stack Overflow question *[Run a ClickOnce application from a webpage without user action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4410783/1132437)*).

Comment: What is your default browser? Have you tried: `Process.Start("iexplore.exe", ApplicationURL)`?

Comment: Ok I just found the answer to my own question.  The problem was that my default browser is google chrome, which doesn't quite know how to handle clickOnce applications.  I changed my code to:

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Iexplore");
    startInfo.Arguments = ApplicationURL;
    Process agentStudio = Process.Start(startInfo);

Now it launches the application using internet explorer, and the application now really works as a "one click" application.

Comment: Thanks M. Babcock, discovered it independently as you replied!

Comment: There is no need to instantiate a `ProcessStartInfo` object if all you're going to do is set the fileName and arguments. This is what the [Process.Start(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) overload is for.

Comment: could you please provide your working answer as a addition to the question or as an answer

Comment: What is your path like? I am able to start one ClickOnce application from another simply by using `Process.Start(<path to .application file>);`. and that is with a UNC path (`\\server\share\folder\program.application`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can start the `iexplore.exe` process to launch a ClickOnce application without any dependency on the default browser. You can also launch the ClickOnce application the same way Windows Explorer launches it, using `dfshim.dll`.

```
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication " + ApplicationURL);
```

There are a few other articles online that discuss using this strategy, but I did not find any official documenation of dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication.

- [Another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733717/what-causes-clickonce-urldownloadtocachefile-failed-during-installation) mentions using a custom .exe to install the .NET Framework and then launch a ClickOnce application via ShOpenVerbApplication.
- Scott Hanselman [discusses ShOpenVerbApplication](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ClickOnceAndFireFoxWithACustomSetupEqualsClickThriceAndBeDisappointed.aspx) as the default file mapping for files with the application/x-ms-application MIME type in a post about Firefox and ClickOnce.

**Update**

As the other Stack Overflow question mentions, you can also use `dfshim.dll`'s `LaunchApplication` command, which is [documented on Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629396.aspx). However, that command is not available in some older versions of the .NET Framework.

Comment: These work great, but how can I get through authentication? The SSRS site requires one, and without the credentials the application download fails. I'm experimenting with combination of InPlaceHostingManager (I know about it already, gave a +1 to @dgp) and a hidden embedded web browser control, but it looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Microsoft walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx) for installing manually via [InPlaceHostingManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.inplacehostingmanager.aspx). You have the ability to customize programmatically.

Comment: Great solution for installing an application, but cannot "launch" the application.

From the documentation: "InPlaceHostingManager can install a ClickOnce application, but cannot execute it. Some methods in this class, such as Execute, are reserved for use when downloading a Windows Presentation Foundation-based application that runs inside a Web browser."

The dfshim method allows for installing and launching.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 other methods for launching ClickOnce applications.

One simple method is `Process.Start("PresentationHost.exe", "-launchApplication " + ApplicationURL);` as documented by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-host-presentationhost-exe).

A more sophisticated method is calling [ShellExecuteEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) Win32 API with code like this:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
info.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info);
info.lpFile = ApplicationURL;
info.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
info.fMask = SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
info.lpClass = "Application.Manifest";
ShellExecuteEx(ref info);
```

Required Win32 API import and structure definitions can be found [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/shellexecuteex.html). This method will query registry and run "rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication" (or anything else that is configured under *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Application.Manifest*).

Answer (score 0):

Following are the ways to launch clickonce.application

**Approach 1:** Launch from URL

Method 1:

```
string app = "http://domain.xyz/ClickOnce.application";
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication " + app);
```

Method 2:

```
string app = "http://domain.xyz/ClickOnce.application";
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", app);
```

**Approach 2:** Directly launch ClickOnce.application from .application file

```
string app = "file://C:/ClickOnce.application";
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication " + app);
```

Answer (score 0):

And another option is using [Launcher::LaunchUriAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions.contenttype?view=winrt-18362) with LauncherOptions.ContentType = "application/x-ms-application". This is known a "uri direct invoke"